# i want when add form by javascript i can sent this form data by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have some code like this:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="send(this);">197.168.0.2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="send(this);">197.168.0.2</a>
<div class="man">
</div>
```

```js
function send(tag){
    var myid=tag.id;
    var mycontent=tag.text;
    rownum++;
    $('.man').append('<div id="rownum'+rownum+'" style="  padding-bottom: 11px;"><_form style="  padding-top: 10px;" id="resultip.html" method="get" ><span class="lb3">IP:</span><_input class="first-in" type="text" id="client'+rownum+'" value="'+mycontent+'" disabled readonly/><span class="lb3">port:</span><_input class="second-in" type="text" name="port"/><_input type="button" onclick="removeRow(this.id);" id="'+rownum+'" class="btn bty" value="cancel"/><button class="btn bty" id="fd">send</button></form_></div>');

$("button").click(function(e) { 
var link=$(this).attr("id");
var url = link;
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: url, data: $('#in'+rowNum).serialize(),
 success: function(data) { $(".error-login").html(data)
  } }); e.preventDefault();
 });  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

i want when add new form by a click i can sent my form data by ajax but i can't.

1. List item

   what can i do to this?

Comment: `id` should be unique in same document, try to change ids added by javascript to classes.

Comment: i did this but my problem is that my ajax code dosn't work